# jquery $.get returns xmlobject

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles with the jquery .get

My code is quite simple:

```
$.get('a.html', function(data) {
    $('.main').html(data)
});
```

Inside a.html there is only:

```
<p> hi </p>
```

It didn't work as data was un XMLObject, I fixed it doing:

```
$.get('a.html', function(data) {
    var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data);
    $('.main').html(xmlString)
});
```

First question, does anybody know why the first code isn't working ?

Now in a.html I have:

```
<form action="contactform_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>name : </p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" id="button">
</form>
```

This is only working if I take off the input flags and again why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offers `.load()` for this type of simple content loading. This:

```
$.get('a.html', function(data) {
    $('.main').html(data)
});
```

becomes:

```
$('.main').load('a.html');
```

As for your other question (*"Why does it assume XML?"*): jQuery tries to determine the data type of the response automatically. That mechanism depends on the `Content-Type` header that the server sends.

Inspect the request in the browser's network console, find out what the server sends. It *should* send `text/html`, if it sends something else, fix your server's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell jquery to expect html by setting the dataType property to html.  If the dataType is unspecified it will try to estimate the return type (xml, json, html) by parsing the content. In your case it will think that the content is xml.

Please check the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/